# Bootstrap full responsive navbar with mini logos for each menu item

Tags: html, image, model-view-controller, icons

I hope you all are fine. I am new here, and I have a question. I am working with mvc , with c#, html, css and boostrap.
I am trying to develop a responsive nav bar.  It contains icons for each menu item. For example, home (a house icon with words under it), item 2, item 3 and so on.
when displaying the nav bar in movile devices ( small screens) the icons in the hamburguer menu continue to be displayed as big as used to be in the computer´s version.
 I would like to adapt the icnons sizes(the brand logo and the items) in the nav bar  for each screen size..here you are the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="brand">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://Brandlogo.com/brandlogo.png alt="">
            </a>

        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <li>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("action1", "item1")">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/item1.png" alt="imagen"> item1
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#cont-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive " src="/images/item2.png " alt="imagen">item2
                    </a>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->

</nav>
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

It enables you to change certain css styles based on screen size.

Comment: thank you very much. I was wondering if there is a more detailed guide or something.

Comment: [this](http://cssmediaqueries.com/what-are-css-media-queries.html) website gives you all the information you need, including realtime testing, a list of possible queries and a list of specific device dimensions. Good luck!

Comment: No problem. Mind accepting my answer if it helped you?